# nmap not working as root

Tags: sudo, nmap

I have a question regarding to nmap. Whenever I try to run nmap as a root, I get:

```
> Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.25 seconds
```

While it works just fine as a non-privileged user. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which server are you trying to nmap? Also, if you add -Pn to nmap's command line arguments, it will make a more precise check.

Comment: Hi thanks for  the reply. I am trying to identify the open network services on a system on a virtual machine on my computer. If I add -Pn than it never terminates..

Answer (score 0):

Answer taken from [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/74493/different-results-using-nmap-with-without-sudo):

Nmap adapts its techniques to use the best available methods using the current privilege level, unless you explicitly request something different. The things that Nmap needs root (or sudo) privilege for on Linux are:

- Sniffing network traffic with libpcap
- Sending raw network traffic

You can use the -d option to see what Nmap is doing in the background, but the short answer is that with root privilege on an Ethernet LAN (like you are using, based on the IP addresses you listed), Nmap will send raw ARP packets and sniff for results. Responding to ARP requests is a prerequisite to IP communication on such a network, so it's nearly impossible to block or hide from this type of scan. If you do *not* have root privilege, Nmap falls back to trying to connect to 2 TCP ports (80 and 443), considering the host "up" if the connection succeeds or is reset. A system with a drop-all firewall and no services on 80 or 443 will not show up with this scan. You can read more about Nmap's host discovery techniques in the [host discovery section of the man page](http://nmap.org/book/man-host-discovery.html).

Comment: the port 80 shows up, but the ports 443 doesn't, however I am trying to learn about exploiting and stuff like that from Metasploitable, and I am doing the instructions exactly the same as the author, however I get very few ports as a non-privileged user, and as root I get nothing.. and one more thing, this may sound stupid, but where did I post the IP address?

Comment: What do you mean by "where did I post the IP address"?

Comment: You said "based on the IP addresses you listed", and I have no idea where did I list any IP addresses

Comment: You didn't. I took the answer from a different StackExchange site, to a slightly different question, as indicated by my first line.

Comment: Oh, sorry I got confused. Thanks for the clarification +1

Comment: Oh looks like I cannot up-vote because the account is new. Sorry that I cannot accept it as the final answer, as it didn't solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the target is in the same lan with you. When run as root in the same lan with target, nmap do ARP scan instead of TCP scan, and there might be a problem with ARP scan(maybe caused by VMware). Could be solved just by adding --disable-arp-ping